# php com word.application outup to html file but unknow file

Tags: php, html, com, header-files

This is my code :

```
$word = new COM("word.application");
$word->Visible = 1;
$word->Documents->Open('./../Team.docx');
$filename = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), "");
$word->Documents[1]->SaveAs($filename);
$word->quit();
unset($word);
//header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-word");
//header("Content-Disposition: attachment;Filename=test.doc");
header('Content-Encoding: UTF-8');
header('Content-type: text/html; charset= UTF-8');
header("Content-Disposition: attachment;Filename=Test.html");
// Send file to browser 
readfile($filename);
unlink($filename);
```

My code in idea to read a file Ms.Word than `SaveAs` it to new file in `HTML` file but it's not correct yet, any one have any idea, pleas suggest me to do it in `PHP`

Answer (score 0):

I am get answer now, I post this answer for to anyone meet problem like me

[convert your file from .doc to .html](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.com.php#20862)